# Why is it possible to have temporary tables without name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Simple reproduction:

```
SELECT ProductID
INTO #
FROM dbo.Products;

SELECT *
FROM #;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#') IS NOT NULL
    PRINT 'Wow';
```

This executes just fine and I'm getting ***Wow*** as a result.

Why/how is it possible?

You can't have real table without name, why temporary tables can be nameless?

Comment: You can also `declare @ int`

Comment: I understood that in local session you're declaring it as a `@`/`#`, but internally it's stored with additional details next to its name, some `GUID` generated during the session. Is that correct?

Comment: There's nothing special about # in this respect. All temp tables have a unique internal name derived, as the metadata is stored in a shared catalog across all sessions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your temporary table is not nameless. Its name is '#'.

> **Local Temp Table**
>   Local temp tables are only available to the current connection for the user; and they are automatically deleted when the user disconnects from instances. Local temporary table name is started with hash ("#") sign.

In short, the docs say it must start with a hash. But no other restrictions are applied (ie length).

Same applies for global temporary tables which start with two hash characters.

More info here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server-2005

Comment: That's quite a strange behaviour, but thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

If you goto

> Database -> Tempdb->temporary tables->

You can find your `#` tables is appended with current `session id`.

something like

`[dbo].#__________0000000894D9]`

Even though the you create a `temp table` with name `#`, to differentiate the temp tables in each session the sql server will **append** `session id` to the temporary table you created. So internally it will not be stored just as `#`